# HTTP(S) POST/GET request over TcpClient [C#]

Tags: c#, .net

I am newbie in C#. How can I create http(s) post, get request on server with TcpClient.
I don’t use HttpWebRequest class. Any good example? Thank you

But, I will use SOCKS proxy, such as TOR. I need used this library starksoft.com/prod_proxy.html, and this library works with TcpClient.

Comment: Is using HttpWebRequest not an option?

Comment: Wouldn't want to do this without HttpWebRequest.

Answer (score 1):

You will want to use the httpWebRequest class, as that is what it is for, it has methods to handle this type of request directly.

Comment: But, I will use SOCKS proxy, such as TOR. I need used this library http://www.starksoft.com/prod_proxy.html, and this library works with TcpClient.